# Determining a total, terminating function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to determine whether for the following type: `((a -> c) -> c) -> a` a total, terminating function can be written using that type as a function signature? I understand that in order for a function to be total it has to be defined for all possible values of its input. However, I am not sure what exactly does it means for a function to be terminating. For a function to be terminating, does it have to return a value (and not go into an infinite loop for example)?

Further, what methods can I use to prove that a total, terminating function can be written using `((a -> c) -> c) -> a`? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: One way to do it, which might not be what you are looking for but it's what I would do, is to give an example of a function that satisfies it. I have a feeling in this case that only one such function exists (which might of course be written in a couple of different ways but probably only one behaviour would satisfy it). Is this a school assignment?

Comment: No, it's just a homework question. But I am not exactly sure how to do it, so I am looking for some guidance.

Comment: This is a function that takes a continuation and then ignores it by just returning the initial value the continuation closed over.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'continuation'?

Comment: Actually I'm starting to believe that there is no total, terminating function for this type signature. But I don't know how I would prove it except with some informal rambling. If I give you my informal rambling I might ruin your assignment

Comment: @ceno980 a continuation is something of a type of the form `(A -> c) -> c`, which (excercise for you!) is generally equivalent to simply `A`.

Comment: ...however, it's actually only equivalent if the type `c` is unconstrained-polymorphic, which is not actually the case for the argument here – it would be if the type were `(∀ c . (a -> c) -> c) -> a`, which is different from the one you gave (and _has_ a possible implementation).

Answer (score 5):

> For a function to be terminating, does it have to return a value (and not go into an infinite loop for example)?

Yes, that's what it means. Specifically, it means that you shouldn't cheat by giving a definition like

```
uncont :: ((a -> c) -> c) -> a
uncont f = uncont f
```

...or `uncont = uncont`, or `uncont = undefined`, all of which would mean you're generating a *bottom value* that can't actually be evaluated to a meaningful result.

---

Generally, to prove that a function of some type can be implemented... just implement it! ...If you can, that is, which ... (*spoiler alert*) you can't in this case! To prove *that*, you need to find a particular type-instantiation for which you could generate an impossible result by calling the function. Such results can usually be found by instantiating the result-type-variable with [the `Void` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Void.html#t:Void), and then demonstrating that you can still produce an *argument* for the function, which leads to a contradiction because the function (by assumption that it's total and terminates) would produce a value of type `Void`, which cannot be possible.

Comment: Could you expand on how you could give an argument for the function if (a :: Void)? (did I understand correctly that this is what you mean you would do?)

Comment: Since you said that this function cannot be implemented, is another way of determining this just looking at the type itself? Since the input of the function is ((a -> c) -> c) and the function is supposed to return 'a', it seems that there is no way for the function to be total since the input parameter is a function that will always return a 'c'? Is this a correct way of looking at the problem?

Comment: @dvaergiller I won't show this here because it's homework, the OP should do it.

Comment: @ceno980 maybe you're thinking the correct thing, but this is not an explanation I would accept for a homework assignment.